# Joytick axis problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using joystick joy package for telerobot, I have find out that this package has small problem.

With the same buttons when I press this button the axis[4] is activated, then I remove the joystick and plug it in difference USB port, then the same button I got difference axis be activated

Can anyone help me explain this issue ??

Thanks much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10234/joytick-axis-problem/) by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-06-11

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-11**:
Can you try: jstest /dev/input/js0 (or what you joy device is) and see if that shows the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Haha,

Sorry all,By accident I press the button "Mode" in my logitech joystick, that cause the axis change :D

Thanks all and have nice day.

---

Originally posted by [embeddedheaven](https://answers.ros.org/users/169/embeddedheaven/) with karma: 121 on 2011-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1